# Add more existing sources to Java project

Tags: java, netbeans

In Netbeans I can create a project using existing sources of Java files. If I want to add additional sources to a project how can I do so?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- right click on project
- "Properties"
- "Sources" (top left in the tree)
- "Source Package Folders:" on the left side of the dialog
- "Add Folder"

Comment: thank you ollins :) is there any way to change that folder icon?

Answer (score 5):

**NetBeans 8.0**
You can copy **complete packages** including sub-packages to the projects `/src/`-folder.
Then `Source » Scan for External Changes` and the new sources will be added automatically.
Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

You can [attach a source JAR](http://wiki.netbeans.org/AttachSourceToLibrary). You also can [use the Import Sources module](https://sites.google.com/site/roguexz2/netbeans) ("File -> Import Sources") to import source files from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I added files directly to the project path from a file manager and NetBeans did not show them in my project tree.

I found a good solution for my needs using git. As it is good practice to use a repository for code tracking code changes and I will be doing it regardless. Anyway my resolution to the issue is:

Check the "Diff to HEAD" on the main project folder from within the NetBeans interface and the new files are now found...While your there double check your changes and commit.