# two folders with source code files in netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans

do you have any idea how to create in a netbeans project two folders with different java packages containig source code?

Like :
Source Packages

Generated Files

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597495/add-more-existing-sources-to-java-project

Comment: thanks :) and some more characters

Comment: Wouldn't say "duplicate". Answers match, questions do not necessarily.