# org.jooq.lambda / java.util.function.AND java.util.stream

Tags: java, netbeans, stream, jooq, java-package

I'm working on a Netbeans project and I'm trying to import these packages but It doesn't exist

---

[Error Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqT95.gif)

---

could someone tell me how to fix this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you cannot find a package, you should download it from its source and then add it to your project. Here you can take a look at [jOOQ/jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL). As about the other two, [make sure you are using Java 8](http://www.wikihow.com/Determine-Java-Version). You will also need to know [how to add packages to your projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597495/add-more-existing-sources-to-java-project) in the future.

Comment: for the first package I tried to add it but doesn't  It says that it's already exist while its not http://www.4shared.com/photo/AqWV9zW_ba/19-07-37_05-46-17_AM.html

Comment: For the second packages, I'm using java 8 but the packages does't exist!! http://www.4shared.com/photo/l-PXq3Guba/19-07-37_05-44-08_AM.html

Comment: and for the first package " org.jooq.lambda " I tried to add it manually and I got this http://www.4shared.com/photo/HsmGSCRRba/19-07-37_11-19-02_AM.html